# Android Studio freezes when trying to refactor package name

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to rename my project's package name. To do so I:

1. Untick "Compact empty middle packages"
2. Focus the directory I want to change and press shift+f6.
3. Enter new package name.

then the refactoring process starts, but when it finishes, Studio freezes. It does not say "Not responding", no errors appear, and I can't do anything with it but kill the process.

When I restart studio, I found two packages: one with the old name and one with the new one. The odd thing is that the new package contains about a half of directories, other half is missing or empty.

I've already tried:

1. Googling
2. Changing graddle version, JRE, JDK version.
3. Rebooting.
4. Cleaning, rebuilding.
5. Different computers (4 different computers)
6. Different Android studio version (now I have 1.5.1, and I also tried 1.3.1 or smth like that)

but I've had no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've found some kind of workaround, here are the steps to rename package

1. Using windows explorer (or linux, whatever) rename a folder, for ex ru.sergeymaslov.app - ru.sergeymaslov.appTest. No magic, just renaim it in explorer.
2. Download (in case you don't have it already) Notepad++.
3. In NPP go Search - Find in Files
4. in the "Directory" field insert the path to your project, for ex C:/Users/Admin/AndroidProjects/AppTest/src/ All we need to do for now is to replace imports, so:
5. We write "ru.sergeymaslov.app" in "Find what" and "ru.sergeymaslov.appTest" in "Replace with" That's it, imports replaced.

   1. Now go find AndroidManifest.xml file, click on the package name and hit shift+f6 (Refactor - Rename) and rename this as well.
   2. Rename all obsolete string that contain the old package name as well (here, in AndroidManifest)
   3. Go check your build.gradle for the package name and rename it as well if needed.
   4. Go to project structure - modules - your project - flavors and check application id there.

I also had to rename everything in my preferenceFile.xml.

Hope this'll help

Answer (score 0):

You are not alone, this happens to me too :)...but I couldn't resolve it with Android Studio. I know this is not the best way but solve my problem.

Since package is only folder inside Project structure if you want to change name of the middle element of the package you could rename the folder in OS explorer, and then in Android Studio go to Edit->Find->Replace in path replace all

**Let me explain with an example:**

You have a project AndroidStudioFreezes with package `com.g2o.sample` so you want to change it to `com.sergueymaslov.sample`. Do this:

1. Go to into your Project using Explorer, and rename  `AndroidStudioFreezes\app\src\main\java\com\g2o` folder to `sergueymaslov`
2. Then in AS go to Edit->Find->Replace in path replace all`package com.g2o.sample;` to `package com.sergueymaslov.sample;`

Hope its helps!

Comment: Thank you for your response! The preoblem is that studio freezes when I "go to Edit->Find->Replace in path replace allpackage com.g2o.sample; to package com.sergueymaslov.sample"